# Python build on AWS CodeBuild failing with deps error - dependancies were not changed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Morning,

I have an app using AWS CodeBuild that is rarely deployed. I went to deploy a tiny change - no change to dependancies and the build now fails. I suspect something in AWS or Python has moved in since I last deployed.

The error is

```
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {simplejson==3.17.3(wheel)}
```

simplejson has never been in requirements.txt so I am not sure why it is suddenly being called out.

Have you seen this before?

Comment: Can you check if any package in your requirement.txt requiring simplejson package?

Comment: Morning. I haven't changed any packages and it used to deploy. The change I made was to some text and no logic. Would the packages suddenly need a new dependency? Apologies, I'm more familiar with npm over pip